# Java and Selenium: Getting the id of list elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-stream

I've got a pretty simple list structure, where the elements have an ID and a custom selector.

I'm struggling a bit getting the value of the ID (and other) selector. I can get the text contents, but the same approach doesn't seem to work for getting the selector values.

```
<ul data-e2e-selector="checkboxliste" class="hb-feltliste">
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hb-checkbox id="tilpasninger-INNGANG" data-e2e-selector="tilpasninger-INNGANG">
  <label class="hb-label" for="tilpasninger-INNGANG">Inngangsparti </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hb-checkbox id="tilpasninger-ETT_PLAN" data-e2e-selector="tilpasninger-ETT_PLAN">
  <label class="hb-label" for="tilpasninger-ETT_PLAN">Alle nødvendige rom på ett plan</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

This code gets the text contents.

```
return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=checkboxliste] li"))
        .stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this, for instance, does NOT get the ID values:

```
List<WebElement> liste = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=checkboxliste] li"));
String valg = helvete.get(0).getAttribute("id").toString();
```

I must admit I'm not good with streams, and I'm trying to modify existing code to learn a bit. But even without that, I cannot seem to get the selector values.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Do you want to return list of input element IDs (list of strings)? Or list of elements inside the <ul> that have ID attribute?

Comment: Elements inside the <li> tags that have either an ID attribute or the custom one. Not necessarily as Strings, since they're supposed to be accessed later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector is wrong, it only selects the `li` elements.
In order to select what you want you need something like:

```
List<WebElement> liste = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=checkboxliste] li [id], [data-e2e-selector=checkboxliste] li [data-e2e-selector]"));
```

This will select any element under your `li` which has either `id` or `data-e2e-selector` attribute.

Also, you have an error in your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hb-checkbox id="tilpasninger-INNGANG" data-e2e-selector="tilpasninger-INNGANG">
```

Class attribute is missing the end quote.

Comment: Thanks, that works. (The html error is because of my manual copy/paste.) How would you go about getting a List<String> instead of List<WebElement>? Can it be done with a Stream(), instead of iterating through the list and creating a new one?

Comment: You can do it like this: `liste.stream().map(elem -> elem.getAttribute("id")).collect(Collectors.toList());`. If the answer was helpful, please accept it.